# jsBlocks with external html template

Tags: javascript, html, templates, jsblocks

Is it possible to move templates to separate files in jsBlocks?
On their website there is only an example with embedded template.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Absolutely. You just have to reference the file using a script tag and provide a custom type so the browser don't interpret it as a JavaScript file.

```
<script src="myTemplate.bt" type="blocks/template"></script>
```

myTemplate.bt

```
<div class="template">{{name}}</div>
```